# json_encode array of data from DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am not sure how to write the following code.

```
    $rowID = $_POST['rowID'];
    if ($listing = $Listings->getData($rowID)) {
        $jsonArray = array(

            'listing_number' => $listing['listing_number'],


        );
        exit(json_encode($jsonArray));
    }
```

When I do it like that, the response is Undefined Index: listing_number.

However, If I write it like this,

```
$rowID = $_POST['rowID'];
if ($listing = $Listings->getData($rowID)) {
    $jsonArray = array(

        'listing_number' => $listing[0],


    );
    exit(json_encode($jsonArray));
}
```

The response is

```
{"listing_number":{"id":"24","client_id":"1","address":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","price":"","listing_number":"asdasdasdasd","remarks":"","link":"","status":"","bd":"","ba":"","lot_sz":"","sq_ft":"","yr":"","type":"","thumb":""}}
```

Which lets me know my SQL is and PHP is correct, I just don't know how to access `$listing['listing_number]` correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you intend to access it from? PHP? JS?

Comment: You need to use `$listing[0]['listing_number']` edit: You said it's an stdClass, so you need to use `$listing[0]->listing_number`

Comment: `$listing = $Listings->getData($rowID)` this data may be array and therefore getting index `0` will give you 1 record. Then you can get `"listing_number"` of that data.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton When I do $listing[0]["listing_number"]. I get this error, "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq it is because of that data in index 0 may be object. therefore you must get it like `$listing[0]->listing_number`

Comment: Then it's `$listing[0]->listing_number` or `$listing[0]->getlisting_number`

Comment: Fantastic, $listing[0]->listing_number worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [GrumpCrouton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827005/grumpycrouton) said in the comment, your query is returning an array of results. So if you want to access a value in the first result, you first need to access this result using it's index : 
`$listing[0]->listing_number`.

```
$rowID = $_POST['rowID'];
if ($listing = $Listings->getData($rowID)) {
    $jsonArray = array(
        'listing_number' => $listing[0]->listing_number,
    );
    exit(json_encode($jsonArray));
}
```

P.S. You can convert object to array using a simple cast ( `$result = (array) $result` ), but it is not a must in your case. Casting your object to array will allow you to acces it's data using `result['key']` rather than `result->key`.